# Is html-webpack-plugin hijacking my express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I've been working through the tutorials at https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/ and they've solidified my understanding of how webpack typically bundles your whole frontend into a script that is run by a barebones HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Output Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This file is in a src directory, which sits in the project root.

I've modified the tutorials slightly by serving that HTML page from an Express server, which looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

const server = express();
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../dist")));
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var indexPath = path.join(__dirname, "../src/index.html");

//create a server object:
server
    .get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.status(200)
        res.sendFile(indexPath);
        //res.send('<h1>I am not the webpack script!</h1>')
    })

module.exports = server
```

So far everything makes sense. This server serves my index.html, which runs the webpack script, and that script causes the HTML page to show some text, images, and CSS. If I uncomment the res.send line, the server serves a one-line website instead.

However, the linked tutorial recommends trying HTML-webpack plugin, and when that comes in I get confused. I understand that the plugin creates an index.html file in the same directory as the bundled scripts (in my case /dist) that incorporates any and all scripts created by webpack. Sure, makes sense. But nothing is explicitly serving that HTML file. However,  if I add the plugin to my webpack config:

```
    entry: {
        app: "./src/index.js",
        print: "./src/print.js"
    },
+   plugins: [
+     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
+       title: 'Output Management',
+     }),
+   ],
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
```

then navigate to localhost:3000 in the browser, it displays the /dist/index.html file, NOT the /src/index.html file. Nothing I do to modify the server.js file changes what is displayed in the browser, but if I stop that server from being listened to I see nothing, so apparently webpack-html-plugin is not creating a server of its own.

So seemingly what is happening is that webpack-html-plugin is not just dynamically creating an HTML file to run bundled scripts, it is also changing the behavior of my server in a way that I am not explicitly instructing it to and seemingly cannot modify.

TLDR: Specifically, something in webpack-html-plugin is causing the root route of my express server to serve /dist/index.html, not /src/index.html as I am explicitly instructing it to. Why?

The repo is at https://github.com/CliffRobinson/webpack-tutorial-sandbox and you can (probably) have a look at codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/CliffRobinson/webpack-tutorial-sandbox/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see if you can replicate this odd behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are serving all the files inside the `dist` directory as static files where your `index.html` is generated by html-webpack-plugin. I'm not sure how paths are handled in express but it seems that static files take precedence over any route defined that is why `dist/index.html` is overriding `/` path.